Print 3d array data as an HTML table of time ranges per day
I have a multi-dimensional array as shown below. I would like to display the data in a table, with each day of the week and its opening and closing times in one row. Expected result of the table is attached below.
I'm not familiar with arrays so I have not really tried anything worth mentioning here.
$times = [
    "opening_time" => [
        "monday" => ["10:30 am", "6:30 pm"],
        "tuesday" => ["12:30 pm"],
        "wednesday" => ["4:30 pm"],
        "thursday" => ["2:30 pm"],
        "friday" => ["4:00 pm"],
        "saturday" => ["6:00 am"],
        "sunday" => []
    ],
    "closing_time" => [
        "monday" => ["6:00 pm", "10:30 pm"],
        "tuesday" => ["7:00 pm"],
        "wednesday" => ["10:00 pm"],
        "thursday" => ["6:30 pm"],
        "friday" => ["11:00 pm"],
        "saturday" => ["6:00 pm"],
        "sunday" => []
    ]
];
 



Will you always have this kind of setup (two-part workday), or are there cases where you have more than two, or just one?

@FiddlingAway there can be more than 2 time-slots, so I need a solution that would print out all slots.

@FiddlingAway By slot, I mean a pair of opening and closing times (eg 10:00 am to 6:00pm). In the array provided, Monday would have 2 time-slots while Sunday has 0 and the other days have 1 each.

I've adjusted the code, to match your requirements. Please take a look.

If I may offer a suggestion - the answer by @mickmackusa is better than the one I offered. Would you be opposed to accepting it as the answer, instead?

@FiddlingAway I have accepted the answer by mickmackusa instead. Thanks to all!

In my opinion, there are far too many loops in @FiddlingAway's answer.  You need one preparatory loop to count the number of needed time slots for the week.  Then you need a nest loop to traverse only the opening times data.
As you traverse the opening times, access the related closing times by their shared day key and index.
Code: (Demo)
$slots = max(array_map('count', $times['opening_time']));
echo '<table>';
foreach ($times['opening_time'] as $day => $opens) {
    echo "<tr><td>$day</td>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $slots; ++$i) {
        printf(
            '<td>%s</td>',
            isset($opens[$i], $times['closing_time'][$day][$i])
                ? "{$opens[$i]} to {$times['closing_time'][$day][$i]}"
                : ''

        );
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';


You can do it like this. Please read the comments within the code, and the notes below the output.
<?php
function renderSlots($columns,$repacked,$day,$time) {
    $html = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
        // Check if slot i is set
        if(isset($time[0][$i])) {
            $html .= '
                <td>'.$time[0][$i].' to '.$repacked[$day]["closing_time"][0][$i].'</td>
            ';
        } else {
            $html .= '
                <td></td>
            ';
        }
    }

    return $html;
}

$times = [
    "opening_time" =>[
        "monday" => [
            0 => "10:00 am",
            1 => "6:30 pm",
            2 => "some other time"
        ],
        "tuesday" => [
            0 => "12:30 pm"
        ],
        "wednesday" => [
            0 => "4:30 pm"
        ],
        "thursday" => [
            0 => "2:30 pm"
        ],
        "friday" => [
            0 => "4:00 pm"
        ],
        "saturday" => [
            0 => "6:00 am"
        ],
        "sunday" => []
    ],
    "closing_time" => [
        "monday" => [
            0 => "6:00 pm",
            1 => "10:30 pm",
            2 => "some other closing time"
        ],
        "tuesday" => [
            0 => "7:00 pm"
        ],
        "wednesday" => [
            0 => "10:00 pm"
        ],
        "thursday" => [
            0 => "6:30 pm"
        ],
        "friday" => [
            0 => "11:00 pm"
        ],
        "saturday" => [
            0 => "6:00 pm"
        ],
        "sunday" => []
    ]
];

// Repacking your original array to be like this
/*
    $arr = [
        day => [
            opening_time => [
                10:00 am
                6:30 pm
            ],
            closing_time => [
                6:00 pm
                10:30 pm
            ]
        ]
        ...
    ];
*/

$repacked = [];

// This is to determine the number of columns we'll need
// Letters a-g are variables, standing in for the number of
// slots in a day
/*
$arr = [
    "monday" => a,
    "tuesday" => b,
    "wednesday" => c,
    "thursday" => d,
    "friday" => e,
    "saturday" => f,
    "sunday" => g 
];
*/
$daySlots = [];


foreach($times as $type=>$days) {
    foreach($days as $day=>$time) {
        if(!isset($repacked[$day][$type])) {
            $repacked[$day][$type] = [];
        }

        $repacked[$day][$type][] = $time;

        if(!isset($daySlots[$day])) {
            $daySlots[$day] = 0;
        }

        $daySlots[$day] = count($time);
    }
}

// Get the max number of work slots
$columns = max($daySlots);

$html = '
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Day</th>
';

// As many columns as there are slots
for($i = 1; $i <= $columns; $i++) {
    $html .= '
        <th>Working hours '.$i.'</th>
    ';
}

$html .= '
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
';

// Loop through days...
foreach($repacked as $day=>$times) {
    $html .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.ucfirst($day).'</td>
    ';

    // ... then through specific opening times
    foreach($times as $type=>$time) {
        // We've already picked this up during one of
        // the previous loop passes, we don't need it now
        if($type === "closing_time") {
            continue;
        }

        // Skip days with no set time - generate $columns number of cells
        if(!$time[0]) {
            $html .= str_repeat('<td></td>'.PHP_EOL,$columns);
            continue;
        }

        // With the outline of the repacked array given in 
        // lines 72-81, $time[0][0] is, in the first run through
        // the loop:
        /*
            $repacked
                $day (e.g. Monday)
                    $type (e.g. opening_time)
                        $time (a nested array, e.g. [ [10:00 am, 6:30 pm] ])
                            $time[0] ( first element of the nested array, e.g. [10:00 am, 6:30 pm] )
                                $time[0][1] (first time, e.g. 10:00 am)
        */

        // Check the slots, and generate columns
        $html .= renderSlots($columns,$repacked,$day,$time);
        
    }

    $html .= '
            </tr>
    ';
}

$html .= '
        </tbody>
    </table>
';

echo $html;
?>

The code above outputs (verbatim, empty lines and all):
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Day</th>

        <th>Working hours 1</th>
    
        <th>Working hours 2</th>
    
        <th>Working hours 3</th>
    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Monday</td>
    
                <td>10:00 am to 6:00 pm</td>
            
                <td>6:30 pm to 10:30 pm</td>
            
                <td>some other time to some other closing time</td>
            
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td>Tuesday</td>
    
                <td>12:30 pm to 7:00 pm</td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td>Wednesday</td>
    
                <td>4:30 pm to 10:00 pm</td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td>Thursday</td>
    
                <td>2:30 pm to 6:30 pm</td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td>Friday</td>
    
                <td>4:00 pm to 11:00 pm</td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td>Saturday</td>
    
                <td>6:00 am to 6:00 pm</td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td>Sunday</td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

            </tr>
    
        </tbody>
    </table>

Test it here.

Notes
I've repacked the initial array, to make it easier to loop through it and generate an HTML string to be rendered later on. The repacking could be avoided if you control the way how the initial table (the one I dubbed $times in the provided code) is formed.
The rendered HTML table is a barebones table - you could provide CSS classes as you loop through it, or in the opening part of the $html variable which contains the thead and tbody.
Also, if you need to style the non-empty (or empty) table cells, you could do that with CSS classes as well.
The code has been adjusted to reflect on your comment - you can now provide N workslots during the day.
